# unchecking Optimal Display for subdivision surface modifier not working in edit mode

Tags: subdivision-surface

Hello im a newbie and i am stuck trying to figure out why unchecking Optimal Display for subdivision surface modifier not working in edit mode but will work in object mode. Seems crucial for modeling. [image]

Comment: Hi :). Works just fine in my Blender 3.2. I wouldn't say it's 'crucial', it just shows simplified wireframe, which is sometimes more convenient.

Comment: Having the same problem in 3.4.0. In edit mode it doesnt show the wireframe of the subdivision modifier :(

Comment: This commentary and [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/283934/35559) suggest a real (possibly simply fixed) anomaly in the application. Perhaps worth a [bug report](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports). ?

Answer (score 2):

If Auto Smooth is turned on, GPU Subdivision won't work, that's why it doesn't show correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 3.5 & have that problem. I find it happens when I have another modifier beneath the subdivision surface modifier (eg. the mirror or solidify modifier).

With either of those modifiers beneath the SubD, you see the more complex wireframe whether "optimal display" is checked or not. Once you apply them or delete them, "optimal display" goes back to operating as normal.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was turning on GPU Subdivision under viewport settings in preferences.